# Expected value, borel measurable function, dependent variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

We are given two random vectors: $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $Y: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ - not necessarily independent, and a Borel measurable function: $g: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(X, Y)$ is integrable.

Show that $$\mathbb{E}(g(X, Y)) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^m} \mathbb{E}(g(x, Y)) \text{d} P_X(x)$$

By $P_X, P_Y$ I mean the distribution of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

If the variables $X, Y$ are independent, then $P_X \times P_Y = P_{(X, Y)}$, so I can easily prove that using Fubini's theorem.

But I cannot establish whether this is true if $X, Y$ are not independent.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: By $P_X$ do you mean the distribution function of $X$?

Comment: By $P_X$ I mean probability measure $P_X(A) = P(\omega \in \Omega \ | \ X(\omega) \in A)$ for $A \in \Sigma$. And $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ is the probability space we work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's true. As a counter-example let $X:\Omega\to [0,1]$ be uniformly distributed. And let $X=Y$, so clearly they are not independent. Then define $$g(x,y):=(x-y)^2$$ Then since $X=Y$, the left hand side of your equation will read $\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]=\mathbb{E}[0]=0$; whereas the right hand side is strictly positive.

Comment: Why is the right hand side strictly positive? $$\mathbb{E}((x-Y)^2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} 1 (x-y)^2 dP_Y(y)$$

Comment: @Bilbo because it's the integral of $\mathbb{E}[(x-Y)^2]$, which is strictly positive.

Comment: Yes, yes, I see, I've just began editing my comment. Thank you!